# How do I reconnect to a Spring Session running in Spring Boot to given a session ID that was obtained from RequestContextHolder?

Tags: java, spring-session

```
RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId()
```

Provides us a session, but I was wondering how do I reconnect back to that session from a GET request?